# Xcode project files folders structure for Swift & MVVM Architecture

Tags: swift, xcode, mvvm, architecture

I am starting a new project today from scratch using Swift and MVVM architecture.
I would like to setup the files & folders structure for the best practice I can for easy and understandable navigation and usage.

Most tutorials suggest:

```
├─ Models
├─ Views
├─ ViewModels
├─ Stores
├─ Helpers
```

But I find it very lacking as I don't really know what would be the best practice to manage the `ViewModels` folder.

Any good suggestions from real world super maintainable projects?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I usually don't divide them up like that. I divide them up in viewControllers. like, folder = Login and it contains `LoginViewController`, `LoginViewModel` and lets say `LoginTextFieldView` and then i have all `models`, `routers` and `newworking` in 1 folder each

Comment: You might look at something like this https://github.com/balitax/MVVM-AC-Template to start with

Comment: you can visit this one https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/dabbling-with-mvvm-in-swift-3-3bbeba61b45b, Model - ViewModel - ViewControls is enough

Answer (score 1):

According to [uncle Bob's Clean Architecture pattern](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), you may divide your code in 3 Layers :

- Presentation : All Code which is Framework ( Cocoa here ) dependant. So Put your Views, ViewModels, Vierwcontrollers, etc.
- Data : All the code interacting with repositories ( Like Network Calls, DB calls, User Defaults, etc )
- Domain : All your Models

Comment: Model view presenter is a great architecture but the question specifically asks about MVVM

Comment: I don't see your point @Maddocks. You can use MVP, MVI, MVVM, MVC or whatever else, the standard of Clean Architecture remains useful

Answer (score 0):

The view files will create data bindings that are implemented as escaping/nonescaping closures in the view model to update ui labels and such when view model variables are updated.

I am unsure how to organize the view folder though since Xcode basically forces you to make view controller files.

```
├─ Model
|-|Employee
|-|Customer
|
├─ View
├─ ViewModel
|-|EmployeeViewModel
|-|CustomerViewModel
|
├─ Utilities
|-|NetworkManagerSingleton
```

Answer (score -2):

```swift
YourProject
│
│ Info.plist
|
├─── Model
│       UserModel.swift
│       ProductModel.swift
│       CartModel.swift
│
├─── View
│       Main.storyboard
│       LaunchScreen.storyboard
│       ProductCell.xib
│
├─── Controller
│       HomeVC.swift
│       ProductsVC.swift
│       CartVC.swift
│
├─── Utilities
│    │
│    └─── Extensions
│            UIViewController+Additions.swift
│            String+Additions.swift
│            Dictionary+Additions.swift
│            UIView+Additions.swift
│
├──── Helpers
│    │ CommonMethods.swift
│    │
│    └─── Constants
│            AppMessages.swift
│            Keys.swift
│            EndPoints.swift
├──── Services
│       APIManager.swift
│       Services.swift
│
```